# Google Earth Web/Online WMS

Tags: google-earth

I am trying to add a WMS service to Google Earth Web/Online: https://earth.google.com/web

I tried importing a .kml file that works in the desktop version of GE but had no success. I also tried adding a tile overlay, which failed as well. I could not find any recommendations for working with WMS services in the google faq/ help docs or on the web. Has anyone been successful with this?

The WMS I would like to add: http://www.geoportal.rlp.de/mapbender/php/wms.php?layer_id=61675&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.1&SERVICE=WMS&withChilds=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WMS overlays currently work in Google Earth Pro, but they do not work in Earth v9.x (web & mobile apps) at this time.

But in Earth for web, you should be able to add a Tile Layer that loads a set of Google Map Tiles (the same tile format as you would use with the Google Maps Platform / Maps API). You need the URL for the tile layer, with the appropriate $[x], $[y] and $[level] variables (note "level" instead of "z").  You'll also want to add the N/S/E/W tile extent coordinates.  And I believe it only supports 256x256 tiles at this time.  Let us know how you're trying to add a tile layer, and we can try to debug that.

Comment: Hello Christiaan, Thank you for your answer. I am trying to add a layer from here: https://www.geoportal.rlp.de/mapbender/php/mod_showMetadata.php?languageCode=en&resource=layer&layout=tabs&id=73160 
I was not able to add the link as described above. They provide several links + a .kml and I am not sure which link to use in this case.

Comment: Hi, I was able to download the KML file for that layer (bottom of the "Interfaces" tab), open it in Earth Pro (desktop app), and it seemed to work fine. I could zoom in to certain areas and see the WMS overlays, so it should work for you in Earth Pro.  Maybe make sure you have the latest version of Earth Pro installed? 

All the other links provided for that layer are for WMS services.  As mentioned, Earth Web/Mobile currently does not support WMS, and that layer doesn't seem to provide a basic "Map Tiles" set, so I don't think there's an easy way to get it into Earth Web at this time.